# ListBlobs() sees only the first folder in the Azure blob container

Tags: c#, recursion, azure-blob-storage

My Azure Blob container holds two virtual folders, A and B, along with some files. I use this code in my project to download the content of the container inside a local folder:

```
private async void Test(string temp, CloudBlobContainer container, string target, string prefix) {
   foreach (var item in container.ListBlobs(prefix)) {
      switch (item) {
         case CloudBlobDirectory directory:
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(temp, directory.Prefix));
            Test(Path.Combine(temp, directory.Prefix), container, target, directory.Prefix);
            break;
      }
   }
   await CopyAll(temp, target, controller); /* Just a function to call at the end of the method*/
}
```

Having a container with this virtual structure:

```
container
   A/
   B/
   one.txt
   two.txt
   ...
```

I want to replicate the same structure on a local folder. The problem is that **B is skipped** and only A is considered by the `foreach`, but if I replace `Test(Path.Combine(temp, directory.Prefix), container, target, directory.Prefix)` with, for example, `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(directory.Prefix)` to just print them, then B is printed to the console. It's evident there's a problem with the recursion, but I'm not able to see it. I use recursion to iterate over the virtual directories in the container, so that the original structure is replicated in the local folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should paste the completed code, we don't know the details of these functions like `Test()` / `CopyAll()` in your post.

But if you want to download all the blobs(including the folders), and keep the same structure in local, you can try the code below:

```
 var conn_str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
 var myContainer = "aaa";

 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(conn_str);
 CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
 CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(myContainer);

 var blobs = blobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix:null,useFlatBlobListing:true);

       
 foreach (var item in blobs)
 {
    switch (item) {
        case CloudBlockBlob blob:
            var filename = blob.Uri.Segments.Last();

            //download the blobs which directly under the container
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(blob.Parent.Prefix))
            {
                blob.DownloadToFile(@"d:\aaa" + "\\" + filename, FileMode.CreateNew);
            }
            else
            {
                //download the blobs which are inside folder
                string a = Path.Combine(@"d:\aaa", blob.Parent.Prefix);

                var mydiretory = Directory.CreateDirectory(a);
                blob.DownloadToFile(mydiretory.FullName + filename, FileMode.CreateNew);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm using this nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, version 11.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/).

Please let me know if you still have more issues about this.

Comment: Thanks! I still can't figure out why my code doesn't work.